# Java dynamic Thread-Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I would like to write a Thread-Pool in Java, which automatically resizes the amount of its workers. Without dynamically resizing this is quite easy, as you can see in the example class below.

In my opinion I should check if I need to add a worker, whenever a task is enqueued. And every time a worker finishes his task, it should check if there are more workers than needed.

```
public class ThreadPool {

private static final int WORKER_THREADS = 5;
private static final int MIN_WORKER_THREADS = 2;

private List<Thread> worker;
private LinkedList<ThreadTask> queue;


public ThreadPool() {
    this.worker = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    this.queue = new LinkedList<ThreadTask>();

    for (int i = 0; i < WORKER_THREADS; i++) {
        addThread();
    }
}

private void addThread() {
    WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread();
    thread.start();
    this.worker.add(thread);
}

public void enque(ThreadTask task) {
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.add(task);

        // ADD WORKER HERE 

        queue.notify();
    }
}

private class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ThreadTask task;
            synchronized (queue) {
                while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
                task = queue.poll();
            }
            try {
                task.run();
                // REMOVE WORKER HERE
            } catch (RuntimeException rte) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But honestly I am not sure, what and how to synchronize. My first guess was to synchronize the list of workerThreads, but this did not actually work at all.

Please don't ask why I want to write a custom ThreadPool - just for learning and demo purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest your class implement [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (or even only the super interface `Executor`), which represents exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--)?

Comment: Please assume that `java.util.concurrent` is not available.

Comment: If I had to develop a thread pool for an environment in which `java.util.concurrent` was not available, then I would _make_ the `java.util.concurrent.Executor` interface available by defining it myself. That would help my thread pool implementation source code to be re-useable in other environments, and it also would be a help to other programmers who needed to read my source code.

Comment: Re, "...automatically resizes the amount of its workers..." Be careful not to make the algorithm too aggressive about adjusting the size. Remember that the whole purpose of a thread pool is to _avoid_ the cost of creating and destroying threads. Of course, you have to balance that against the need to avoid letting idle threads claim too much of the system's memory.  But anyway, you may want to avoid killing off idle threads until they have been idle for a while (where, "a while" may be as little as a few seconds.)

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to achieve what ForkJoinPool is doing. You may get some inspiration from there. 
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)